# R - Check if each value in each column is less than the median of that column

Tags: r

I have a data frame that contains several hundred columns of numeric data.  For each column, I need to get the median of all the values in that column, then create a new column, where each cell is true if the value from the original column in that row is greater than or equal to the median, and false otherwise. The new column must then be added to the data frame.

Thank you.

Comment: hi can you please provide a reproducible example. what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding to @asfas answer since it is not complete imo:

```
# randomly generating data
set.seed(11)
# example df
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), c = rnorm(10))
# new df cbound with the TRUE/FALSE columns
df1 <- cbind(df, sapply(df, function(x){
  x >= median(x)
}))
# rename to be able to keep track which T/F column belongs to each value column
names(df1)[(length(df1) - length(df) + 1) : length(df1)] <- paste(names(df), "TRUE/FALSE")
# result
df1
            a          b           c a TRUE/FALSE b TRUE/FALSE c TRUE/FALSE
1  -0.8490129  0.4534761 -0.06477369        FALSE         TRUE         TRUE
2   2.3396931 -0.1234337  0.31549629         TRUE        FALSE         TRUE
3  -0.1212030 -0.7630968 -0.60568155         TRUE        FALSE        FALSE
4  -1.9502074  0.2282701 -0.90758469        FALSE         TRUE        FALSE
5   0.5387115  1.1194619  2.26160898         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE
6   1.6935148  0.1565732 -0.60322671         TRUE        FALSE         TRUE
7  -0.7909682 -0.6887721 -1.29786210        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE
8  -1.0752606  0.4529496  0.50645120        FALSE         TRUE         TRUE
9  -0.6078751 -1.0675467 -0.85333426        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE
10  0.7544017  0.4015651 -1.50603179         TRUE         TRUE        FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cbind(mtcars, setNames(lapply(mtcars, function(x)
    x >= median(x)), paste0(names(mtcars), "_")))
```

Comment: Actually this is a working answer. However, we do not only post code on Stack Overflow but also offer some explanations.